# When to use drmModeFreeResources after a drmModeGetResources?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, gpu, linux-device-driver

If I'm working with drm on linux and trying to get the number of displays/connectors on a gpu, when do I need to call drmModeFreeResources/Connector?

```
drmModeResPtr drmResources = drmModeGetResources(drmFd);

for (int i = 0; i < drmResources->count_connectors; i++) {
    drmModeConnectorPtr connector;
    connector = drmModeGetConnector(drmFd, drmResources->connectors[i]);
    if (connector && connector->connection == DRM_MODE_CONNECTED) {
        do_something();
    }
    drmModeFreeConnector(connector); // Do I need to do this?
}
drmModeFreeResources(drmResources); // Do I need to do this?
```

Do I need to free every time I get resources/connector? Or do I only need to do it after I'm done with the resources and want to destroy them, such as when the connector or display is no longer connected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(About 9 years after the question was asked, but it still isn't obvious 9 years later from drm documentation...)

The drmGet/Free* functions return (and free) pointers to memory they allocate. The Get functions use ioctl() to get info for filling the data from the kernel. The Free functions just free() the memory allocated in the Get functions; they do nothing with ioctl(). So as long as you don't hold onto any of the pointers, or memory pointed to by them, you can call the drmFree* function once you are done inspecting them.

For my project, this meant making sure to copy the struct pointed to by drmModeModeInfo, rather than keeping a pointer to the mode, and later passing the copied struct into drmModeSetCrtc(), since I obtained it by iterating through entries in info returned from drmModeGetConnector(). You could also just hang onto all the memory returned by drmModeGetConnector() and then call drmModeFreeConnector() when you're finished with drm.